# Компилятор protobuf не видит descriptor.proto

Tags: golang, google-protobuf

у меня есть такой proto файл:

```
syntax = "proto3";

option go_package = "./;newtype";

package my.types;

import "google/protobuf/descriptor.proto";

extend google.protobuf.FieldOptions{
  optional string my_size = 50001;
}

message Block{
  bytes arr = 1 [(my_size) = "3"];
}
```

Путь к файлу:

> /${PATH}/proto/newtype/block.proto

Я компилирую данный файл командой:

```
protoc --proto_path=/${PATH}/proto/newtype --go_out=. block.proto
```

И получаю ошибку:

> PCName newtype % ls -al
> total 8
> drwxr-xr-x  3 Username staff    96  6 окт 10:04 .
>
> drwxr-xr-x  5 Username  staff   160 30 сен 12:10 ..
>
> -rw-r--r--  1 Username  staff  1527  6 окт 10:04 block.proto
>
> PCName newtype % protoc --proto_path=/{$PATH}/proto/newtype -I$(go env
> GOPATH)/pkg  --go_out=. block.proto
> google/protobuf/descriptor.proto: File not found.   block.proto:7:1:
> Import "google/protobuf/descriptor.proto" was not found or had errors.
> block.proto:9:8: "google.protobuf.FieldOptions" is not defined.
> block.proto: "google.protobuf.FieldOptions" is not defined.

Как указать компилятору protobuf где ему искать файл descriptor.proto?

Comment: попробуйте `protoc -I./ -I$(GOPATH)/src  --go_out=. block.proto ${PATH}/proto/newtype`

Comment: Получил ошибку:
zsh: command not found: GOPATH
/src: warning: directory does not exist.

Comment: попробуйте без `-I$(GOPATH)/src`, но вам в любом случае нужно задать GOPATH

Comment: да, надо в переменной системы еще создать

Comment: Сделал, ту же ошибку пишет, что descriptor.proto не найден.
И у меня в GOPATH нету папки src есть bin и pkg. Я попробовал обе

Comment: вывполните команду `ls -al` и потом вашу команду. результат приложите к вопросу

Comment: пожалуйста. отредактируйте вопрос и вставьте в сам вопрос этот выввод

Comment: Подправил вопрос

Comment: https://pastebin.com/yN7kxbGX 
создал папку пустую. залил прото-файл. выполнил команду и все сгенерировалось. проверьте версию protoc

Comment: У меня версия protobuf:  
```libprotoc 3.17.3```

Comment: Решил проблему переустановкой компилятора protoc.

Answer (score 0):

protobuf те еще танцы с бубнами, тоже были проблемы с ним решал я их так:

это мой Maikefile

```
install-protobuf-compiler-for-linux: 
    sudo  apt install -y protobuf-compiler
    protoc --version
    make get-protobuf-dependencies

proto-version ?= v1.3.2
get-protobuf-dependencies:
    go get github.com/golang/protobuf/protoc-gen-go@v1.4.3
    go get github.com/gogo/protobuf/proto@$(proto-version)
    go get github.com/gogo/protobuf/protoc-gen-gogo@$(proto-version)
    go get github.com/gogo/protobuf/gogoproto@$(proto-version)
    go get github.com/gogo/protobuf/protoc-gen-gofast@$(proto-version)
    go get github.com/gogo/protobuf/protoc-gen-gogofast@$(proto-version)
    go get github.com/gogo/protobuf/protoc-gen-gogofaster@$(proto-version)

cp-protobuf-package:
    # костыль
    mkdir -p $(GOPATH)/src/github.com/gogo/
    cp -r $(GOPATH)/pkg/mod/github.com/gogo/protobuf@$(proto-version) $(GOPATH)/src/github.com/gogo/protobuf




clear:
    find ./ -name *.gen.go -delete
    find ./ -name *pb.go -delete
    find ./ -name prog.go -delete
    find ./ -name *gen.go.tmp -delete

generate-proto:
    go generate ./protobuf

generate:  clear generate-proto
    go generate ./...
```

выполняю по очереди

сами протобаф файлы храню в 1 месте + держу go файл где прописаны команды для генерации каждого файла в том порядке, в котором для меня удобно.

[image: protobuf_dir]

так выглядит сам файл где прописаны команды для генерации, посмотрите может быть вам что-то поможет

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]